# For Google Rich Snippets, should the last item in a breadcrumb be a link?

Tags: google-search, microdata, rich-snippets, breadcrumbs

A website has the following breadcrumb trail when on the "Labrador" page:

> [Services](http://example.com/services) > [Squirrel Chasing](http://example.com/services/squirrel-chasing) > Labrador

As you may notice, the current page is not linked to. (There is an internal reason with a difficult solution.)

The last item in [Google’s recommended (data-vocabulary.org) Microdata markup](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en) will be missing the `itemprop="url"` attribute, with only:

- `itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb"`,
- and `itemprop="title"`.

**Is the lack of a link to the current page an issue?**

The goal is to have the above breadcrumbs appear in Google search results, for example:

> [image: Breadcrumb rich snippet example in Google SERP]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including the current page in the breadcrumbs is not required by [Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en):

> Each breadcrumb item should appear in order, with the first item
>   representing the top-level page, and the **final item representing the
>   parent of the current page**.

Therefore, it should not matter if it is marked up at all.

However, the effects of marking it up with everything apart from the URL are still unknown to me.

Answer (score 2):

Current breadcrumbs markup in schema.org is a crap. A lot of discussions, but current issues are still not solved. Check out the latest [thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2013Jun/0045.html) about it at public-vocabs. The best attempt for now to solve it is [here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/WebSchemas/Breadcrumbs) (not accepted).

I advise you to use Google's [markup](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185417?hl=en) since you're mostly interested in this SE.

Comment: I hadn't realized that Schema.org markup for breadcrumbs isn't the same as the data-vocabulary.org recommended by Google — I updated the question, thanks +1